# Rails: Route ignoring parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am using the below to render a collection:

`<%= render :partial => 'mini_release', collection: group, as: :r %>`

And the following routes:

```
constraints(domain: /[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i, page: /[0-9]+/, :format => 'html') do
    get ':domain', :to => 'sites#show', as: :site
    get ':domain/releases(/p-:page)', :to => 'sites#releases', as: :site_releases, :constraints => { :format => /(json|html)/ }
    get ':domain/release/:release_id', :to => 'sites#release', as: :site_release
end
```

All good so far, the routing works and the rendering works. However, when calling the path below inside the partial "mini_release", it builds an incorrect url:

`<%= link_to site_release_path(:domain => r.site.domain, :release_id => r), :class => 'col-xs-6' do %>`

Where `r` is a model of `Release` and has one `Site` (which has an attribute `domain`).

The URL generated is correct in terms of the URL is builds. But the `:domain` section is always incorrect and is the current models object.

For example, say the page I am currently on is: `/site-one/release/my-release/` and I am rendering the partials, all the partials result in `/site-one/release/the-correct-slugs`, when they should be `/some-other-site/release/the-correct-slugs`. I've tried multiple formats for the routes - with and without the variable associations - but none work. It seems the route is taking the current route `:domain` parameter instead of the given one.

How can I ensure the route stops looking at the current `:domain` parameter?

This may have something to do with this https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9829

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently rails doesn't like the parameter name `:domain`. I renamed it to `:domain_id` and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should actually be linked to the way your compute the domain

Can you check (by printing it on the page for example or using debugger) that r.site.domain returns the correct domain ?

This may not be linked to the routes.

EDIT

If r.site.domain is returning what you want inside the partial, then could it have something to do with the constraint on domain param. Does the string returned by r.site.domain pass the constraint ?

Comment: Afraid not, nothing changes

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the constraint makes no difference. This may have something to do with https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9829